# Attention is All You Need: How to calculate params number of the models?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, llm

I want to re-calculate the last column of Table 3 of *[Attention is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762)*,
i.e. number of params in the models.
But numbers from my calculation do not match.

| Model | Params from Table 3 ($\times 10^6$) | My Calculation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| base | 65 | 63014912 |
| B (1) | 58 | 55937024 |
| B (2) | 60 | 58296320 |
| big | 213 | 214110208 |

My calculations are as following:

Number of parameters in each multi-head attention layer:

$$
N_{att} = N(W^O) + (N(W_i^Q) + N(W_i^K) + N(W_i^V)) \times h
$$

$$
= h \times d_v \times d_{model} +
   (d_{model} \times d_k + d_{model} \times d_k + d_{model} \times d_v) \times h
$$

where $N(.)$ is the size (number of elements) of a matrix.

Number of parameters in each Feed Forward Network:

$$
N_{FFN} = 2 \times d_{model} \times d_{ff} + d_{model} + d_{ff}
$$

Therefore, the total number of parameters is:

$$
2 N \times N_{FFN} + (N + 2 N) N_{att} + N_{voc}  \times n_{model}
$$

where $N_{voc}$ (the size of the vocabulary) is $37000$
according to section 5.1.

Substituting all numbers in Table 3 into the above formula, we get
$63014912$ for *base* model. If let $N_{voc}$ be $40000$, then
the numbers for *base*, *(A)* ~ *(E)* models seem to be matched
with those in the table, but $217182208$ is got
for *big* model, while $213M$ is given in the table.